# Using Http.Client in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, json.net

I've looked into few similar questions but couldn't find where my problem is. First I tried with adding the android permissions for INTERNET first (didn't worked). So this is the method I am using to get a data for the Air Polution forecast and then update my UI. Before this same code was fine with UWP project and now I'm trying to make it work under Android also. There is not much help from VS why I am getting this exception but the code does not run after I call the http.GetAsync(url)

```
public async static Task<airQualityRootObject> GetAirQualityForecast(string url)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url); // There's unknown exception here
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        airQualityRootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<airQualityRootObject>(result);
        return data;
    }
```

And here is the code that calls that same method

```
public async void GetAirPolutionData(string url)
    {
        //Get data for Air Polutoin from the service
        airQualityObject = await AirQuality.GetAirQualityForecast(airQualityURL);

        //Update the UI screen
        lblAirStatus.Text = "Air Polution Level Forecast for Today: "
            + airQualityObject.currentForecast[0].forecastBand
            + Environment.NewLine
            + airQualityObject.currentForecast[0].forecastSummary
            + Environment.NewLine
            + Environment.NewLine
            + "Air Polution Level Forecast for Tomorrow: "
            + airQualityObject.currentForecast[1].forecastBand
            + Environment.NewLine
            + airQualityObject.currentForecast[1].forecastSummary;
    }
```

I don't understand, Am I calling it wrong or there's something wrong with the method itself? Also why this same C# code is working fine under UWP but its causing me problems on Android?

Comment: First, you should reuse your `HttpClient` and dispose your Response/Result after usage. Second, can you access the android internet browser without problems?

Comment: I have access to the browser inside the emulator if that's what you meant. I can open any web page. And by "reuse" you mean?